Why did Violet Evergarden quit her job in the movie?
I am highly confused about why Evergarden quit her job, a job that she loves, a place to heal others and herself, and a place with new friends. Why did she quit a job that she loves just for Gilbert, who was hiding from her for 2 years? WHY? Gilbert is also a pervert and a coward. 
